# Kendo bar chart does not show data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart, telerik-charting

Struggling to display the data from the Model into the Kendo Bar chart. 
I want bar chart to display the results  as shown in the following figure

[image]

The controller returns valid data but chart fails to display the data properly.

Model is

```
public class FeeCollectionViewModel
 {
     [Key]
     public int FeeCollectionID { get; set; }
     public int StudentID { get; set; }
     public int FeeModeID { get; set; }
     public int FeeTypeID { get; set; }
     public string FeeTypeName { get; set; }
     public double Amount { get; set; }
     public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is the View

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fee Statistics";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Fee Statistics</h2>

 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<SMS.ViewModels.FeeCollectionViewModel>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("Today's Collection")
        .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
        )
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Read(read => read.Action("TodaysCollection_Read", "FeeCollections"))
            .Group(group => group.Add(model => model.FeeTypeName))
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Column(model => model.Amount).Name("Amount Collected");
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .Categories(model => model.FeeTypeName)
            .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
            .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        )
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
            .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
            .MajorUnit(10000)
            .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Format("{0:N0}")
        )
)
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `.AutoBind(true)` ? Also check for any related javascript errors in the console and if any other controls have the ID `chart` in the view or layout.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Chart does not perform groupby sum. I had to do it in the controller and pass the resulting model to the chart.

```
    List<FeeCollectionChartViewModel> result = (from f in feeCollections
                                                group f by f.FeeTypeName into g
                                                select new FeeCollectionChartViewModel()
                                                        {
                                                            FeeTypeName = g.Key,
                                                            Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                                                        }).ToList();
     return Json(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not parsing data to input Chart
[I create object by input chart and pass data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQ5L.png)

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ha7l.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Posting link-only answers are usually frowned upon because the link could disappear over time. Please consider copying and pasting the data relevant to the question in to your answer.